# How to make the loop pause until user input in telegram python bot?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, telegram, telegram-bot

```
        for job in jobs:
        def gen_markup():
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.row_width = 1
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='לאתר מתגייסים', url=job[3]))
            return markup
        if int(job[6]) <= int(user.dpr):
            if str(user.sex) == 'זכר':
                if int(user.profil) >= int(job[7]) and int(user.profil) <= int(job[8]):
                    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>" + str(job[1]) + "</b>" + "\n" + str(job[2]), reply_markup = gen_markup(), parse_mode='HTML')
                    // here i want to ask user if he wants to continue the jobs loop
            else:
                if int(user.profil) >= int(job[9]) and int(user.profil) <= int(job[10]):
                    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>" + str(job[1]) + "</b>" + "\n" + str(job[2]), reply_markup = gen_markup(), parse_mode='HTML')
                    // here i want to ask user if he wants to continue the jobs loop
```

Hello, I have difficulty implementing thing which will pause the loop until the user input (until he will want to continue the loop). What do I need to write in code for doing that?

Comment: Is that a function definition inside a loop? At any rate, you ask the user for input and then do a `if/else` based on their answer where the `else:` would just be `break`.

Comment: But how do I ask the user for input and pause the loop?

Comment: The loop will pause automatically awaiting user input once it hits that line of code in your logic flow. It can't proceed with following logic without that line's request being fulfilled.

Comment: Okay, what do I need to write to make it happen?

Comment: I answered, but I realize now reading your code this is specific to telagram/bot where I am assuming you are interacting with the user.  My aplogies.